# how to structure vuejs dynamic components?

Tags: vue.js

I have a component Main in Main.js. i am using `<component>` here to dynamic render components 'A', 'B', and 'C'. i am passing the data from Main to each of them using props. but the thing is that there are some data which is only used by 'A' and are not used by 'B' and 'C'. also other way around. But i am using `component` i have to pass the data to 'B' and 'C' also.
I know there is not any problem but here still.
i am thinking to use computed here. will it be good?

Answer (score 0):

If your config object depends on some data then ye, computed is your solution. If you're wondering how to structure reusable components in general then I'd recommend you this article: https://michaelnthiessen.com/6-levels-of-reusability/